# Rudin Functional Analysis regarding the Minkowski functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a convex absorbing set on some vector space $X$ and $x\in X$. In the proof of theorem 1.35 of Rudin's Functional Analysis, he states that if $\epsilon\in(0,\infty)$, then $t:=\mu_A(x)+\epsilon$ is such that $t^{-1}x\in A$. However, I don't see why this is true. It seems to me that he is using something of the sort: if $t>\mu_A(x):=\inf\{\lambda\in(0,\infty)|\lambda^{-1}x\in A\}$ then $t^{-1}x\in A$. However, the condition $t>\mu_A(x)$ only guarantees that $t$ is not an upper bound, i.e. that there is a positive $\lambda<t$ such that $\lambda^{-1}x\in A$. Of course, if $A$ was assumed to be balanced, one would then have $t^{-1}x=t^{-1}\lambda\lambda^{-1}x\in t^{-1}\lambda A\subseteq A$, given that $t^{-1}\lambda<1$. This however was not assumed. Is there something obvious I am not seeing?

Comment: How are you accounting for the convexity of $A$?

Comment: I don't know how to resolve this using the convexity. If I had a $\mu>t$ for which $\mu^{-1}x\in A$, then a convex combination of $\mu^{-1}x$ and $\lambda^{-1}x$ would yield $\lambda^{-1}x\in A$. I however do not know how to guarantee the existence of such a $\mu$.

Comment: In fact, I only need a $\nu<\lambda^{-1}$, for then I would obtain $t^{-1}x$ as a convex combination between $\nu x$ and $\lambda^{-1}x$. In particular, if $A$ was symmetric $x\in A\Leftrightarrow -x\in A$, we could take $\nu=-1$.

Comment: Oh got it! I just saw in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854616/how-to-show-mu-ax-inf-alpha0-alpha-1-x-in-a-where-mu-ax-is?rq=1 that indeed $0\in A$. Thus we can take $\nu=0$. Thanks!